# NDepend query to detemine what methods in other DLLs are being called

Tags: ndepend

We have a very large code base with multiple teams owning different layers.  One team would like to know what methods and types are being called so they can centralize them.  So for a set of DLL's and executables which we put in a NDepend project, what query would give us all methods and that are used and are contained in assemblies that begin with the name 'Company.ODS'.

Comment: Please elaborate on the goal you are trying to achieve. Thanks.

Comment: Again, we have a set DLL's and executables - we want to know every method and type used in that set that is contained in Company.ODS assembly.    For example assembly Order has calls methods Inventory.Save and Inventory.Change.  Those two methods are defined in assembly Company.ODS.  I want those methods in my result set.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to write this query.

In both cases `let assembliesUsed = Application.Assemblies.WithNameIn("Infrastructure", "ApplicationCore")` is the part to adapt to your code like for example `let assembliesUsed = Assemblies.Where(a => a.Name.StartsWith("CompanyName.Feature"))`

---

A) Present results with types/methods/fields **used**.

```
let assembliesUsed = Application.Assemblies.WithNameIn("Infrastructure", "ApplicationCore")

let typesUsed = assembliesUsed.ChildTypes().ToHashSetEx()
let membersUsed = assembliesUsed.ChildMembers().ToHashSetEx()

let typesUser = Application.Types.UsingAny(typesUsed).Where(
  t => !assembliesUsed.Contains(t.ParentAssembly))

let methodsUser = Application.Methods.UsingAny(membersUsed).Where(
  m => !assembliesUsed.Contains(m.ParentAssembly))

from x in assembliesUsed.ChildTypesAndMembers()
let users = 
  x.IsMethod ? x.AsMethod.MethodsCallingMe.Intersect(methodsUser).Cast<IMember>() : 
  x.IsField ?  x.AsField.MethodsUsingMe.Intersect(methodsUser).Cast<IMember>() : 
               x.AsType.TypesUsingMe.Intersect(typesUser)
where users.Any()
select new { x, users }
```

[image: DLLs assemblies coupling indexed by used code elements]

---

B) Present results with types/methods **users**.

```
let assembliesUsed = Application.Assemblies.WithNameIn("Infrastructure", "ApplicationCore")

let typesUsed = assembliesUsed.ChildTypes().ToHashSetEx()
let membersUsed = assembliesUsed.ChildMembers().ToHashSetEx()

let typesUser = Application.Types.UsingAny(typesUsed).Where(
  t => !assembliesUsed.Contains(t.ParentAssembly))

let methodsUser = Application.Methods.UsingAny(membersUsed).Where(
  m => !assembliesUsed.Contains(m.ParentAssembly))

from x in methodsUser.Concat<IMember>(typesUser)

let used = 
  x.IsMethod ? x.AsMethod.MembersUsed.Intersect(membersUsed) : 
               x.AsType.TypesUsed.Intersect(typesUsed) 
where typesUsed.Any()
select new { x, used }
```

[image: DLLs assemblies coupling indexed by user code elements]

Comment: this seems to be returning the methods that call methods in Company.ODS, we want a list of the Company.ODS methodsbeing called from DLL's in the project. I want what you get when click on a item in the 'used' column. You can see that in the screenshot you provided above for ApplicationCore. I want to get the unique list and export it to Excel. 

Another issue I see that is annoying when I cut from somewhere (i.e. a web page, notes) and paste into the query text box, the text disappears and a red box is left. I then need to type the query in manually.